# How to add missing locale to Intl.DateTimeFormat (ES2020) if browser doesn't support required locale?

Tags: vuejs2, polyfills, ecmascript-2020

Unfortunately some browsers don't support some locales using Intl.DateTimeFormat. In my case 'kk' locale in Chrome (https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/icu/scripts/chrome_ui_languages.list). You can test your locale in console:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat.supportedLocalesOf('kk')
```

If it returns empty array [] it means that it doesn't support.

My question is how to add missing locale? I mean may be there is a Polyfill for that? I'm using Vuejs 2

Comment: Q: What is your question?  How to install 'kk' (Kazakh) locale on your workstation so that Chrome can use it with your VueJS app?

Comment: Edited question above.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found solution to use Polyfill:

```
npm i @formatjs/intl-datetimeformat
```

Then in your code:

```
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/polyfill-force’ // Using force to use our polyfill
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/kk’ // Add locales you want
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/ru’ // Add locales you want
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/add-all-tz' // Add ALL tz data
```

Comment: What I dislike about this library is that it does not work without `polyfill-force` and if you decide to actually use `polyfill-force`, you must import all the locales you would like to use and not utilise the locales that already exist within the browser which inflates the compiled package.  Has anyone else found other ways around this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a solution to only polyfill those locales that aren't already present in Intl.DateTimeFormat. In my case browsers are missing only `kk` locale. Therefore I only want to polyfill `kk` with @formatjs and use `en` & `ru` via original Intl.DateTimeFormat.

```
import {
  DateTimeFormat as PolyfillDateTimeFormat,
} from "@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat";

const LOCALES_THAT_ARE_POLYFILLED = ["kk"];

const OriginalDateTimeFormat = Intl.DateTimeFormat;

const DynamicDateTimeFormat = new Proxy(PolyfillDateTimeFormat, {
  construct(target, args) {
    if (LOCALES_THAT_ARE_POLYFILLED.includes(args[0])) {
      return new target(...args);
    } else {
      return OriginalDateTimeFormat(...args);
    }
  },
  get(target, prop) {
    if (prop === "supportedLocalesOf") {
      return (value: string | string[], options?: Pick<Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions, "localeMatcher">) => {
        if (typeof value === "string") {
          if (LOCALES_THAT_ARE_POLYFILLED.includes(value)) {
            return target.supportedLocalesOf(value, options);
          } else {
            return OriginalDateTimeFormat.supportedLocalesOf(value, options);
          }
        } else {
          return value.map((locale) => {
            if (LOCALES_THAT_ARE_POLYFILLED.includes(locale)) {
              return target.supportedLocalesOf(locale, options)[0];
            } else {
              return OriginalDateTimeFormat.supportedLocalesOf(locale, options)[0];
            }
          });
        }
      }
    } else {
      // @ts-ignore
      return target[prop];
    }
  }
});

// also keep in mind to monkey-patch toLocaleString, toLocaleTimeString, toLocaleDateString
Object.defineProperty(Intl, "DateTimeFormat", {
  value: DynamicDateTimeFormat,
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  writable: true,
});

const _promise = Promise.all([
  import("@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/kk"), // need to be statically defined for bundlers
]);
```